# How to perform recursive delete in xslt at last elements of string

Tags: xslt

In one of my xml message I have a particular tag in which some (unknown) of last positions are filled with a particular character(/). But during XSLT I want to remove this character and generate another string free from that characters in last positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a string which may end with zero or more slashes; you want a function or a template to strip the trailing slashes -- but not other slashes -- from the string.  In XSLT 2.0, the simplest thing to do is write a function to do this.  There are many ways to write the function; a straightforward one is this one (which generalizes the problem to stripping any given character off the end of a string, not just slash):

```
<xsl:function name="my:strip-trailing-char">
  <xsl:param name="s" required="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="c" required="yes"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ends-with($s,$c)">
      <xsl:value-of select="my:strip-trailing-char(
             substring($s,1,string-length($s) - 1), 
             $c
      )"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

In XSLT 1.0, you can do the same thing with a named template:

```
<xsl:template name="my:strip-trailing-char">
  <xsl:param name="s" required="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="c" required="yes"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ends-with($s,$c)">
      <xsl:call-template name="my:strip-trailing-char">
        <xsl:with-param name="s" 
          select="substring($s,1,string-length($s) - 1)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="c" select="$c"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @sperberg thanks for the answer. Going forward can u tell me how can i add these slashes to my string. For example if i have an address field which i need to have 30 characters but in case my xml message provides me only 20 characters i need to fill them by some special characters.Since i don't know how much character my message is going to provide me i would hve to create a generlize function for it.

Comment: One way to pad a string (call it $s) to 30 characters, with slashes, is substring(concat($s,'//////////////////////////////'),1,30).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but you would create an identity transform that copied every element recursively, with a special template for the elements you want to modify, like this

```
<xsl:template match="particular-tag">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will remove all characters from the first slash onwards from every `<particular-tag>` element.